# How to simulate a reaction with an order < 1 in pyomo?

Tags: python, ode, pyomo

I am simulating a chemical reaction of the form A --> B --> C using a chemical batch reactor model. The corresponding ODE is a follows:

dcA/dt = - kA * cA(t) ** nA1

dcB/dt =  kA * cA(t) ** nA1 - kB * cB(t) **nB2

dcC/dt = - kB * cB(t) ** nB2

Pyomo solves the ODE system fine if the exponents nA1 and nB2 are 1 or higher. But in my case they below 1 and as the components concentrations approach zero the ode integration fails, giving out only nans. The reason is that once the concentrations approach zero they numerically become values of cA(t) = -10e-20 for example and then the expression cA(t)**nA1 is not solvable any more.

I tried to implement a workaround of the form:

```
if cA < 0: 
   R1 = 0
else: 
   R1 = kA * cA(t) ** nA1
```

but I wasn't able to do it properly as I had a hard time using the pyomo synthax.

This is the minimal working example:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.dae import *

V = 40     # l
kA = 0.5   # 1/min
kB = 0.1   # 1/min
nA1 = 0.5
nB2 = 0.5
cAf = 2.0  # mol/l

def batch_plot(t, y): 
    plt.plot(t, y[:, 0], label = "cA")
    plt.plot(t, y[:, 1], label = "cB")
    plt.plot(t, y[:, 2], label = "cC")
    plt.legend()

def batch():
    m = ConcreteModel()

    m.t = ContinuousSet(bounds = (0, 500))

    m.cA = Var(m.t, domain = NonNegativeReals)
    m.cB = Var(m.t, domain = NonNegativeReals)
    m.cC = Var(m.t, domain = NonNegativeReals)

    m.dcA = DerivativeVar(m.cA, wrt = m.t)
    m.dcB = DerivativeVar(m.cB, wrt = m.t)
    m.dcC = DerivativeVar(m.cC, wrt = m.t)

    m.cA[0] = cAf
    m.cB[0] = 0
    m.cC[0] = 0


    R1 = lambda m, t: kA * m.cA[t] ** nA1
    R2 = lambda m, t: kB * m.cB[t] ** nB2


    m.odeA = Constraint(m.t, rule = lambda m, t: m.dcA[t] == - R1(m, t) ) 
    m.odeB = Constraint(m.t, 
                       rule = lambda m, t: m.dcB[t] == R1(m, t) - R2(m, t) ) 
    m.odeC = Constraint(m.t, 
                       rule = lambda m, t: m.dcC[t] == R2(m, t) )

    return m

tsim, profiles = Simulator(batch(), package = "scipy").simulate(numpoints = 100)

batch_plot(tsim, profiles)
```

I expect the ode integration to work even with reaction orders below 1.

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two aims in modifying the power function `x^n`:

- extend to negative `x` in a smooth way so that the numerical method does not hiccup close to `x=0` and
- have a small slope for small `x` so that the numerical integration for very small `x` has a greater chance to be stable.

The first condition is satisfied by constructs like

- `x*max(eps,abs(x))^(n-1)` or
- `x*(eps+abs(x-eps))^(n-1)`,
- `x*(eps^2+abs(x-eps)^2)^(0.5*(n-1))`,

which all have the exact same value `x^n` for `x>eps` and are continuous and piecewise smooth. But the slope at `x=0` is of the size `eps^(n-1)` which will require very small step sizes even after the system stabilizes.

The solution is to extract even more integer power from the rational power in the form of

```
x*abs(x) * max(eps,abs(x))^(n-2)
```

or one of the other variants for the last factor. For `0<x<eps` and `n=0.5` this results in the value `r(x)=x^2 * eps^(-1.5)`, so that the equation `x'=-k*r(x)` has the solution `x(t)=x1/(1+x1*k*eps^(-1.5)*(t-t1))` after it fell to a point `0<x1<eps` at `t=t1`. The slope of `r` is smaller `2`, which is nice for numerical integrators.

This was implemented for `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`, using method `LSODA` and rather strict tolerances, with the ODE right side function

```
# your original function, stabilizes at negative values
power0 = lambda x,n: max(0,x) ** n; 
# linear at x=0, small step sizes   
def power1(x,n): eps=1e-4; return x * max(eps, abs(x)) ** (n-1);  
def power2(x,n): eps=1e-4; return x * (eps**2+(x-eps)**2) ** (0.5*(n-1))
# quadratic at x=0, large step sizes on the tail
eps = 1e-8
power3 = lambda x,n: x * abs(x) * max(eps,abs(x)) ** (n-2)
power4 = lambda x,n: x * abs(x) * (eps**2+(x-eps)**2) ** (0.5*n-1)  
# select the power approximation used  
power = power3

def model(t,u):
    cA, cB, Cc = u;
    R1 = kA * power(cA, nA1)
    R2 = kB * power(cB, nB2)
    return [ -R1, R1-R2, R2 ]
```

The integration runs successfully, using step sizes 20-30 in the tail end. The resulting plot looks qualitatively correct,

[image: plot of the solution]

and in the zoom for small values is smooth and remains positive.

[image: zoom towards the t axis]